# Picture with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to do the following picture with TikZ.
[image]

The code I currently have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill,pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue!30] (-5,0)--(0,0)--(0,2)node[below left]{AIR}--(-5,2)--cycle;
\draw[fill,pattern=north east lines, pattern color=black!30] (5,0)--(0,0)--(0,2)node[below right]{EAU}--(5,2)--cycle;
\definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.15,0.95,0.15}
grid [step=0.5];
\draw[-,>=latex](-5,1)--(0,1);
\draw[-,>=latex](0,1)--(5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I  cannot get  the pink rectangle, nor write the words *AIR*, *EAU*, and *VIDE* as seen in the picture.

Comment: To put text anywhere you use `\node[text options] at (coordinate) {text};` To draw a pink rectangle: `\draw[fill=red!20] (one corner coordinates) rectangle (opposite corner coordinates);`

Comment: You can look at the `\node` command from the manual; it allows you to place text at a chosen location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get you started:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [draw=blue, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue!30] (-5,0) rectangle (5,2);
\draw[fill=white] (-5,1) -| (-1,1.5) -| (0,2) -- (-5,2) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=red!20] (0,0) rectangle (0.4,2);
\node at (2.5,1) {EAU};
\node at (-2.5,1.5) {AIR};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that, first I drew the whole "water" rectangle, and then put on top of it the irregular "air" white shape, and the pink rectangle. For the "air" I used the notation `-|` to connect coordinates with lines which go, first horizontal, then vertical.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you so much, just, please how we can make arrow and write VIDE in the exteriror of the domain, like in the picture?

Comment: You can use `\node` again to put the test "VIDE" at the appropiate coordinates. `\draw[->]` draws an arrow between two arbitrary coordinates. This is pretty basic stuff, perhaps you should read the initial examples in TikZ manual.